# Angular: Create a new occurrence of an object for every month

Tags: angular, typescript

Basically I want to have an object "Activity", that when i create it, I want to automatically create an activity for each month.

Example:

```
export class Activity {

      activityID = string;
      activityName = string;
      startDate = Date;
      endDate = Date;
    }
```

Let's say I create an Activity called "haircut", and i set the startDate at 01/01/2020 and the endDate at 31/12/2020. And I know that every month for that date range i must have an activity telling me to get a haircut.

How is this possible in Angular 8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use of the package [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) to manipulate time and get your dates.

In your code :

```
import * as moment from 'moment';

const m  = moment(yourStartDate);

do {
   m.add(1, 'months');

   // ...

   // While your date is not passed your endDate
} while ( ... );
```

Here is the [doc](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/) about the add

Comment: Thanks! This definitely looks like what I need. Will try it out.

Comment: Can I use this in Typescript or is it only for Javascript?